# Does broidered rhyme with whirred?

Tags: pronunciation, rhymes

Does broidered rhyme with whirred?

https://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=whirred&typeofrhyme=perfect&org1=syl&org2=l&org3=y

Rhymezone says it doesn't rhyme, but another dictionary says it does rhyme:

https://www.rhymer.com/broidered.html

Shouldn't broidered rhyme with whirred? And could you explain why it doesn't?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "rhyme".

Comment: Both your sources look like they're machine generated, so I wouldn't trust them as far as advice on what rhymes and what doesn't.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The "ered" in *broidered* is an unstressed syllable, and *whirred* is a stressed syllable, and generally we don't rhyme totally unstressed syllables with stressed syllables. (But even though *sobered* doesn't rhyme with *word*, we could get away with rhyming *sobered* with *snowbird* and *snowbird* with *word*, since the syllable *bird* in *snowbird* has an intermediate amount of stress on it.)

Comment: [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masculine_and_feminine_endings) explains the difference between masculine and feminine rhymes.

Comment: They just about rhyme in some accents, some Scots accents for example, but not in Received Pronunciation. Note that in accents where "(em)broidered" rhymes with "whirred"  both of them rhyme with "bird" but in accents where they do not rhyme "embroidered" does not rhyme with "bird".

Answer (score 1):

They do not rhyme:

- *whirred* sounds like *word* if you have the wine-whine merger so /wɜːd/, or /ʍɜːd/ if not
- *broidered* (perhaps *embroidered* is more common) is /bɹɔɪdəd/, so a different vowel sound and length at the end

Comment: So https://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=broidered&typeofrhyme=perfect&org1=syl&org2=l&org3=y broidered only rhymes with embroidered?

Comment: That depends on what counts as a rhyme when the final syllable is unstressed, but for example *blundered* is closer in rhyme to *broidered* than *whirred* is